# Properly handle windows OS scaling with pyqt4

Tags: windows, user-interface, screen, pyqt4

After a long development on some standard screens with pyqt4, I have tested my program on a new surface from windows, with the high resolution screen.  I guess windows 8.1 is set for some scaling to handle applications.

When loading the program on this new screen, the text all scales, but the buttons layouts etc. do not.  This causes text to go outside the box, and become unreadable.

Is there a way in PyQt4 to handle this type of scaling properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question was not answered, the only option I have found is the latest Qt5.4 has now implemented this ability. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html

If another answer comes along for Qt4 I will accept that instead.